# Microsoft Bot Framework Composer - Send Slack Block Kit

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

Using Microsoft Bot Framework Composer, I would like to send a response to a Slack channel using Block Kit. I've tried creating a response with a JSON attachment, but the bot returns:

> The bot encountered an error or bug. To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code.

````
# SendActivity_pTmt7x()
[Activity
    Attachments = ${json(SendActivity_pTmt7x_attachment_R1WWzr())}
]

# SendActivity_pTmt7x_attachment_R1WWzr()
> To learn more about the LG file format, read the documentation at
> https://aka.ms/lg-file-format
- ${SlackMessage()}

# SlackMessage()

- # slackmessage
- ```

{

"type": "Attachment",
"name": "blocks",
  "content": [
    {
      "type": "section",
      "text": {
        "type": "mrkdwn",
        "text": "This is a sample Slack Block Kit"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "divider"
    }
  ]
}
````

[image]

Is it possible to construct a Response that can render Block Kit UI properly in Slack?

Comment: Where did you find that syntax for putting block kit in a Bot Framework attachment? Can you link to any documentation or samples you've been following?

Comment: I following the example code here. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66575227/botframework-composer-and-slack-block-kit

But this is different than what is listed on MSFT docs.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-channeldata?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

I've tried all the combinations I could think of.

Comment: Are you using the C# Slack adapter like Martin La Rosa was?

Comment: Yes. Created a new C# Empty Bot template and added the Slack Adaptor via Composer's package manager.

Comment: Linking: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/8177

Comment: Kyle, how do I know if the slack adaptor is being used in Composer? I enabled the Slack channel in Azure, but is there something else I need to do in Composer?

Comment: It looks like you figured it out. Would you like to accept your own answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Slack Adaptor was not properly configured. I disabled the Slack channel in Azure Bot configuration and setup the Slack Adaptor in Composer.

[image]

```
# slackmessage()`enter code here`

- '''
{
    "type" : "Attachment",

    "name": "blocks",
    "content":
[
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "Hello, Assistant to the Regional Manager Dwight! *Michael Scott* wants to know where you'd like to take the Paper Company investors to dinner tonight.\n\n *Please select a restaurant:*"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "divider"
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "*Farmhouse Thai Cuisine*\n:star::star::star::star: 1528 reviews\n They do have some vegan options, like the roti and curry, plus they have a ton of salad stuff and noodles can be ordered without meat!! They have something for everyone here"
            },
            "accessory": {
                "type": "image",
                "image_url": "https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/c7ed05m9lC2EmA3Aruue7A/o.jpg",
                "alt_text": "alt text for image"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "*Kin Khao*\n:star::star::star::star: 1638 reviews\n The sticky rice also goes wonderfully with the caramelized pork belly, which is absolutely melt-in-your-mouth and so soft."
            },
            "accessory": {
                "type": "image",
                "image_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/korel-1YjNtFtJlMTaC26A/o.jpg",
                "alt_text": "alt text for image"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "*Ler Ros*\n:star::star::star::star: 2082 reviews\n I would really recommend the  Yum Koh Moo Yang - Spicy lime dressing and roasted quick marinated pork shoulder, basil leaves, chili & rice powder."
            },
            "accessory": {
                "type": "image",
                "image_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/DawwNigKJ2ckPeDeDM7jAg/o.jpg",
                "alt_text": "alt text for image"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "divider"
        },
        {
            "type": "actions",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "button",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "Farmhouse",
                        "emoji": true
                    },
                    "value": "click_me_123"
                },
                {
                    "type": "button",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "Kin Khao",
                        "emoji": true
                    },
                    "value": "click_me_123",
                    "url": "https://google.com"
                },
                {
                    "type": "button",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "Ler Ros",
                        "emoji": true
                    },
                    "value": "click_me_123",
                    "url": "https://google.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}


'''


# SendActivity_Qy4SoS()
[Activity
 Attachments = ${json(slackmessage())}
]
```

[image]